# How to call contextmanager ignoring yielded value (in one line)?

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

For instance:

```
@contextmanager
def add_stuff(arg):
    parser = Parser(arg)
    # do something here
    yield parser
    # do something there
    do_stuff(parser)
```

Usually, I call it like this:

```
with add_stuff("foo") as p:
  p.add_more_stuff(1, 2, 3)
  p.add_more_stuff(4, 5, 6)
```

But sometimes I don't need to "add more stuff"

```
with add_stuff("foo"):
  pass
```

---

Is there a way to call `add_stuff` in one line (w/o violating pep8 by putting `pass` on the same line)?

---

Example below doesn't work because `add_stuff` is not just generator and is not iteratable:

```
list(add_stuff("foo"))
```

Or should I just add some util func?

```
def wizz(gen):
  with gen:
    pass

wizz(add_stuff("foo"))
```

Or keep using `with`...

Comment: `with add_stuff("foo"): pass` is awfully unintuitive; that definitely needs to be commented. Or replaced with a call to a helper function.

Comment: what's the benefit of calling a context manager without utilizing a returned value?

Comment: You can just do `do_stuff(Parser("foo"))` without `add_stuff`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest usually I use that context manager while utilizing returned value, but sometimes I don't. But I still need to call the same manager in order to create an empty parser and later add it to the registry.

Comment: @Sanyash the code in question is simplified. In reality, there are tens of lines before and after `yield`

Comment: You can write separate function which is not a context manager and looks like `def simple_stuff(arg): parser = Parser(arg); do_stuff(parser)`. If you don't like to do it - your util function looks ok and can be the simplest solution.

Comment: In terms of design - such approach doesn't give a reasonable benefit. Create a separate structure that could perform the 1st processing phase

Answer (score 0):

```
def use(cm):
    with cm:
        pass
```

Then `use(add_stuff("foo"))` is PEP 8-y.